# Boost - Cannot wrap pass-in vriables

Tags: python, c++, boost

I tried to wrap a list to a vector of string using `<boost/python>`, where comes "undefined symbol" error:

```
/* *.cpp */
using namespace std;
using namespace boost::python;

// convert python list to vector
vector<string> list_to_vec_string(list& l) {
    vector<string> vec;
    for (int i = 0; i < len(l); ++i)
        vec.push_back(extract<string>( l[i] ));
    return vec;
};

bool validateKeywords(list& l){
    vector<string> keywords = list_to_vec_string(l);
    // do somethoing
};
```

And I have

```
/* wrapper.cpp */
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(testmodule){
    // expose just one function
    def("validateKeywords", validateKeywords);
}
```

When import the module, returns the error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/testmodule.so: undefined symbol: _Z16validateKeywordsSt6vectorISsSaISsEE
```

In my testing, everything works fine if I just convert returned values, i.e. from `vector<string>` to `list`. Just couldn't make it work with pass-in variables. Unless you pass in types that do not need a wrapper (int, char, bool, void), the problem doesn't fade away.

---

**Update**

What you can do:

```
/*pass in a variable that do not need a wrapper*/
// testmodule.cpp
void sayHello(const std::string& msg) {
    std::cout << msg << endl;
}
// wrapper.cpp
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(testmodule) {
    def("sayHello", sayHello);
}
// demo.py
import testmodule as tm
tm.sayHello('hello!')
// output
>> hello!

/*wrap a returned value from a function*/
// testmodule.cpp
vector<int> vecint(int i) {
    vector<int> v(i);
    return v;
}
// wrapper.cpp
boost::python::list vecint_wrapper(int i) {
    boost::python::list l;
    vector<int> v = vecint(i);
    for (int j=0; j<v.size(); ++j)
        l.append(v[j]);
    return l; // then you have a list
}

/*cannot change passed in values to more complicate types*/
```

Answer (score 1):

You miss get reference in line:

```
def("validateKeywords", validateKeywords);
```

Try to use

```
def("validateKeywords", &validateKeywords );
```

Comment: Nope, using `arg` is ambiguous, it should precede `boost::python::` to specify. And this still seems to cause same problem.

Comment: sadly, the problem still exists. Due to poor documentations I still do not quite understand the stuff.

Comment: @knh170 Also, you use std and boost::python namespaces. In both this namespaces defined type list. Probably, you should directly specify boost::python::list as function argument type?

Comment: Not the problem. If there's a conflict, compiler will tell you. I found a solution: define the convert function in wrapper, and expose it to python. But I don't understand the problem.

Comment: And it doesn't allow C++ type exists in Python, so this doesn't provide a real solution too, since I can't pass converted variable to C++ function.

Comment: @knh170 "And it doesn't allow C++ type exists in Python" - if you doesn't write a wrapper for them. As I think, boost::python::list class must have wrapper and converter, which provides automatic type conversion python list to boost::python::list.

Comment: Yeah, it does. It just converts returned value. It worked fine. Just cannot make it work with pass-in variables.

Answer (score 0):

I got. You can't define the wrapper in C++ implementation, but you can do it in wrapper layer. Though I don't know why, but you can:

```
/* wrapper.cpp */
bool validateKeys(list l) {
    vector<string> keys;
    // so you can accept a python list!
    for (int i; i < len(l); ++i) keys.push_back(extract<string>(l[i]));
    return validateKeywords(keys);
}

// module
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(testmodule){
    def("validateKeys", validateKeys); // use wrapped function, just that simple
}
```